# Django Find Out if User is Authenticated in Custom Tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to create a custom tag. Inside this custom tag, I want to be able to have some logic that checks if the user is logged in, and then have the tag rendered accordingly. This is what I have:

```
def user_actions(context):
    request = template.Variable('request').resolve(context)
    return { 'auth': request['user'].is_athenticated() }

register.inclusion_tag('layout_elements/user_actions.html', takes_context=True)(user_actions)
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [request] in u'[{}]'
```

The view that renders this ends like this:

```
return render_to_response('start/home.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Why doesn't the tag get a RequestContext object instead of the Context object? How can I get the tag to receive the RequestContext instead of the Context?

EDIT:

Whether or not it's possible to get a RequestContext inside a custom tag, I'd still be interested to know the "correct" or best way to determine a user's authentication state from within the custom tag. If that's not possible, then perhaps that kind of logic belongs elsewhere? Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just passing the "user" parameter to the tag and using that to decide if the user was auth'd or not.

Answer (score 3):

By default, an instance of `django.template.Context` is used in rendering templates, but you can override this in your view, either by passing a subclass of `django.template.Context` as the `context_instance` keyword argument to `render_to_response`, or by instantiating the subclass, and passing it directly to `Template.render`.

For convenience, Django provides a useful, pre-defined `Context` subclass: `django.template.RequestContext`. `RequestContext` looks in your settings file for a setting called [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/settings/#template-context-processors), which should be a tuple of callable objects, each of which should return a dictionary; `RequestContext` will loop over each callable, call it, and add the key/value pairs from its returned dictionary to the template context as variables. Check out [these](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter10/) [links](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/) for a more detailed explanation.

To add the current user to your template context, you need `django.core.context_processors.auth`:

1. Add the `django.core.context_processors.auth` context
   processor to your list of context
   processors in `settings.py`:

   ```
   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
       'django.core.context_processors.auth',
       ... # Other context processors follow
   )
   ```
2. Ensure the view than renders the template which calls
   your custom tag uses `RequestContext`:

   ```
   from django.template.context import RequestContext
   from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
   def my_view(request):
       # Do some stuff
       return render_to_response('templates/view.html', 
           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
   ```
3. Using `RequestContext` calls all context processors defined
   in `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, including the
   `auth` context processor, which adds a context variable 'user'
   to your template context.
   In your template tag, you can access this variable
   via `context['user']`

   ```
   @register.inclusion_tag('templates/custom/tag.html', takes_context=True)
   def custom_tag(context):
       user = context['user']
       if user.is_authenticated():
           # Some stuff for the logged-in users
       else:
           # Stuff for anonymous users
   ```

Comment: that's more or less what everyone is telling me, but for some reason it is not working. I get "Caught KeyError while rendering: 'user'" on the context['user'] line.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps above? Make sure `django.core.context_processors.auth` is in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting; use `RequestContext` in your view rendering the template (generic views do this by default)? It might help if you could post your settings.py, views.py and custom template code.

Comment: Yes, all that was done. In my question, you can see my template code and the return of the view. I can promise you that TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS has django.core.context_processor.auth (or whatever the non-deprecated version is) in it.

Comment: It should be `if user.is_authenticated:` without the parentheses, else it would return a "Boolean is not callable" error.

Answer (score 1):

i dont see how your view is linked to the template tag, because from what i know its django's template system that renders the tag,  so the context is a dictionary, try this, hopefully it helps

```
user = context['user']
if  user.is_authenticated():
     do stuff
```

Comment: when I use context['user'], I get: Caught KeyError while rendering: 'user'

Comment: That is most likely because there is not supposed to be a user entry in the template node context

Comment: is there anyway to determine if the user is authenticated or not from within the tag?

Answer (score 1):

The "context" of a template node is a different thing to the `RequestContext`. A `Context` is also a dictionary, so if it has a user at all it would be accessed via `context['user']`.

The template nodes context contains information to help it render itself within the template, after doing some reading of the docs, I cannot find any way to access the `RequestContext` which would be associated with the request via the `django.template.Context`.

---

Moreover `django.template.RequestContext` extends from `django.template.Context` specifically in order to handle the added request object which would contain the user. So it is no surprise that `Context` would not have access to it.

See the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/context.py#L67) of `Context` for proof.

### How to get the user

After a bit of searching I found the `django.template.resolve_variable` method which can be used as follows:

```
from django.template import resolve_variable

user = resolve_variable('user', context)
```

Where `context` is a template context.

Comment: Also, when a `RequestContext` is passed to a function, the parameter name is typically `request`.  If you see `context`, it's probably a `Context`.

Comment: Then what is the best method of determining if a user is logged in from within a custom tag?

Comment: I only brought up the RequestContext because in the docs it says that if the setting are correct, it can have a 'user' entry. I assumed that might be a good way to get it in the tag. Perhaps I am wrong. I'm perfectly ok with using anything else. I'd just like to know the "correct" way to check for user authentication within a tag.

Comment: I think I found a solution to get the user, not sure if it works but it looks good. I added it to the end of my answer.

Comment: That gave me this error: Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [user] in u'[{}]'

Comment: Doing this: template.Variable('user').resolve(context) yields the same error as well.

Comment: I found it in [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1576/). Are you using it in the same way?

Comment: @Marcus: your solution would only work if 'user' already existed in the current context; if it does, `context['user']` would work just as well (and is a lot simpler :). Besides, I believe `resolve_variable` is deprecated, in favor of `django.template.Variable.resolve`.

Comment: Yer, maybe that is why I hadn't seen it before. Well the first part of the answer is still correct (as you point out) so you would just need to ensure, as your answer explains, that `django.core.context_processors.auth` needs to be present in the settings file.